# Running total and moving average

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum, moving-average

What is the genre-wise running total and moving average of the average movie duration? You need to show the output table in the question.

Output format:

| genre | avg_duration | running_avg_duration | moving_avg_duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| comedy | 145 | 102.44 | 134 |
| … | … | … | … |

Genre table:

| movie_id | genre |
| --- | --- |
| … | … |

Movie table:

| id | title | year | date_published | duration | country | worldwide_gross_income | languages | production_company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| … | … | … | … | … | … | … | … | … |

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem and the content of the input tables?

Comment: I prefer an "exponential moving average".  With that one needs to remember only one value from one row to the next.  Also, any kind of moving average is clumsy to compute in SQL; I recommend doing it in your app code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT genre,
    ROUND(AVG(duration),2) AS avg_duration,
    SUM(ROUND(AVG(duration),2)) OVER(ORDER BY genre ROWS UNBOUNDED 
    PRECEDING) AS running_total_duration,
    AVG(ROUND(AVG(duration),2)) OVER(ORDER BY genre ROWS 10 PRECEDING) 
    AS moving_avg_duration
FROM movie AS m 
INNER JOIN genre AS g 
ON m.id= g.movie_id
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY genre;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT genre,
ROUND(AVG(duration),2) AS avg_duration,
SUM(ROUND(AVG(duration),2)) OVER(ORDER BY genre ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) 'running_total_duration',
AVG(ROUND(AVG(duration),2)) OVER(ORDER BY genre ROWS 10 PRECEDING )  'moving_avg_duration'
FROM movie AS m
INNER JOIN genre AS g
ON m.id=g.movie_id
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY genre;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.